# Hide keyboard when user taps outside a password box inside a user control - WIn 8 C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, user-controls, keyboard, settings

I have created a the following `CustomControl` to show the Settings from the `SettingsPane`

```
<UserControl
x:Class="xxx.Flyouts.LCSettings"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="xxx.Flyouts"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignWidth="400">


<Border BorderThickness="1,0,0,0">
    <Grid Background="LightGray" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Header area for panel -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" Margin="40,0,0,0" >
                <Button Click="MySettingsBackClicked" Margin="4,4,0,1"  Style="{StaticResource SettingsBackButtonStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" FontFamily="{StaticResource PeaSnow}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="SemiLight" FontSize="24.6667" Text="General" Foreground="#FF0C0B0B"/>
            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>

        <Grid x:Name="SettingsGrid" Grid.Row="1" Margin="40,33,40,39">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock x:Name="newPasswordTBlock" Text="New Password" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="SemiLight" FontSize="20"/>
                <PasswordBox x:Name="newPwdBox" IsPasswordRevealButtonEnabled="True" Background="LightGray" LostFocus="OnPasswordLostFocus" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="confirmPasswordTBlock" Text="Confirm Password" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="SemiLight" FontSize="20"/>
                <PasswordBox x:Name="confirmPwdBox" IsPasswordRevealButtonEnabled="True" Background="LightGray"/>
                <Button x:Name="pwdButton" Content="Ok" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="SemiLight" FontSize="20" Click="OnPwdButClicked"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="pwdDescrip" Text="" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="SemiLight" FontSize="20"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="blankTBlock2" Text="" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="SemiLight" FontSize="16" TextAlignment="Center" MinHeight="50"/>

            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>


    </Grid>
</Border>
```

When I click on the passwordbox, the keyboard pops up but on clicking outside the box, it does not dismiss. I tried to set a LostFocus on the password box, but it is not triggered when i click outside the box. I can see the cursor still blinking inside the password box.

Is the keyboard not dismissing because it is a Flyout which comes over the main page? How do I solve this? :(